# HDR option grayed out on Samsung A50 camera

Tags: settings, camera, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-a5

[image: Camera settings]

I can not turn on HDR. It is grayed out. I tried all modes front and rear camera and it is always Grayed out and I cant turn It on. I am using a Samsung Galaxy A50 that I recently bought and Samsung live chat support was not helpful. I am on the latest software.

Comment: According to a [forum entry](https://r2.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-A/HDR-mode-in-Samsung-Galaxy-A50/td-p/1899452) HDR only works with an aspect ratio other than 3:4 and a resolution below 25MP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Robert said in the above comment, I have switched from 3:4H (25 megapixels) to 3:4. And HDR now works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was in the photo mode of the camera. After I switched to video mode and then went to the setting, then I could toggle the auto HDR.